# Safari cannot render/process decimal point in CSS

Tags: css, firefox, google-chrome, safari, decimal

I am doing responsive layout design, i figure out safari cannot render decimal point value, it will round off, and break the design layout.

I am using Mac Lion Safari 6.0

Here is an example, try launch in safari,firefox,google chrome

Look at the right border
http://dabblet.com/gist/3324471

I am using twitter bootstrap grid system. It render perfectly on google chrome and firefox but not safari.

There is any way to solve safari's decimal point rendering problem??

Answer (score 0):

You could always try using percentages, if you haven't done so already. Also, I'm looking at the page in Safari 6.0 under Mountain Lion, and it looks great, no abnormal margins whatsoever.

Comment: i am in home and only have one computer with only one operating system

Comment: look at the most right side of all the four row, it is not balance, but in chrome,firefox , it is calculated in balance

Comment: That's true. Must've missed that.